# Silverlight WCF service binding error, "The remote server ..:Not found"

Tags: wcf, silverlight

this is my first post on here. Normally, I find my answer on other threads, but this time I'm really stumped.

I have a Silverlight App and I can connect to my webservice to send/receive data just fine, except for one page that I have. All the other pages, I can get data, make changes and send it back to the service. This one page, I try to send data to a service and it gives me a login box for the web server. Whether I put in my credentials or not, I get the error "The remote server returned an error: Not found." I have a combobox that gets loaded on Page Load event and it gets the data from the service just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="Network_Integrity_Control_Panel.Web.Service_AD_SQL.customBinding0">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Negotiate"/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment 
            aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="Network_Integrity_Control_Panel.Web.Service_AD_SQL">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Network_Integrity_Control_Panel.Web.Service_AD_SQL.customBinding0"
                          contract="Network_Integrity_Control_Panel.Web.Service_AD_SQL" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Network_Integrity_Control_Panel.Web.Service_AD_SQL.customBinding0" 
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , Welcome to `SO`  .

It gives you a login box because your Authentication mode is `Windows`

What I see from your config  your endpoint address is empty `address=""`.

You should give the address in your code or in your config file.

Have a look at Microsoft resources http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I do have authentication as Windows, but I make calls to the service from other buttons and it works fine. I actually narrowed it down to one button on my page that gives me that login box. The rest of the web app doesn't. In the link provided, the address is empty as well in the example. I thought by doing this, I am telling it that the service is in the root folder. Is there any other code that I can provide that can help you help me? lol